# Does non-zero and finite Hausdorff dimension imply non-zero and finite Hausdorff measure?

Tags: measure-theory, geometric-measure-theory, dimension-theory-analysis, hausdorff-measure

Is it possible that a set $A$ has Hausdorff dimension $d=\mathrm{dim}_H (A)\in (0, \infty) $ but $ H^d (A)\notin (0, \infty) $? In other words, positive and finite Hausdorff dimension but its Hausdorff measure is never positive and finite?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An example is the real line $\mathbb R$ with its usual metric.  Then
$$
1 = \dim_H(\mathbb R),\quad\text{but}\quad H^1(\mathbb R) = +\infty
$$

See [HERE](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1583531/442) for an example of a subset $A$ of $\mathbb R$ with
$$
1 = \dim_H(A),\quad\text{but}\quad H^1(A) = 0 .
$$